# What is the regex expression to trim trailing/leading spaces/tabs from first line in the CSV file?

Tags: python, regex

Consider the CSV dataset as below:

```
"Column1 "," Column2"," Column3 ","Column4","Column5"
"Record11 "," Record12"," Record13 ","Record14","Record15"
"Record21 "," Record22"," Record23 ","Record24","Record25"
"Record31 "," Record32"," Record33 ","Record34","Record35"
```

After applying the regex expression on the csv dataset
Expected output:

```
"Column1","Column2","Column3","Column4","Column5" >trailing/leading space removed from row1
"Record11 "," Record12"," Record13 ","Record14","Record15" > other rows should remain intact
"Record21 "," Record22"," Record23 ","Record24","Record25" > other rows should remain intact
"Record31 "," Record32"," Record33 ","Record34","Record35" > other rows should remain intact
```

PLEASE NOTE : The trailing/leading space/tabs could be in any row and regex should handle only any row/record given by user.

I have tried python **re.sub()** function with expression as "\s*([^"]*[^"\s])\s*" and replace it with **"\1"**. But using this regex replace expression it applies for all the records of the csv file but the expectation is to apply only for first row.

Please note that we are bound to use only re.sub() python method.

Comment: In which form is that _CSV dataset_ represented in your Python program or elsewhere? With which string(s) have you _tried_ _**re.sub()**_?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [str.strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip), which does what you need - you would call it on a per-element basis.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how to make the match only work on the first line if
you have to apply the regex on all the content of the CSV file.

But, if you know the number of columns or calculate it by counting them
on the first line, then **you can call `re.sub()` with the
fourth parameter (*count*) set to the number of columns**.
This way it will stop and only apply the changes on the first row.

For the regex pattern itself, I would do something like this:

```
/
"              # opening quote.
\s*            # spaces to drop at the begin.
(?P<text>      # capturing group named "text"
  (?:          # non-capturing group, repeated 0 or n times, ungreedy.
    "{2}|[^\"] # either an escaped quote (2 quotes) or any non-quote char.
  )*?
)
\s*            # spaces to drop at the end.
"(?!")         # closing quote, not followed by a quote. This is to
               # make the ungreedy text capturing work correctly.
/gx
```

This will work in case you have some quotes inside the string.
In CSV, quotes are not escaped with `\"` but they are doubled `""`.

You can test the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/t4UAyZ/4

You'll notice that you can't just count commas to count the number
of columns as commas can also be in the strings themselves.

Python code:

```py
import re

csv = """\"Column1 \",\" Column2\",\" Column3 \",\"Column4\",\"\"\"stupid\"\",\"\"col\"\" name \"
\"Record11 \",\" Record12\",\" Record13 \",\"Record14\",\"Record15\"
\"Record21 \",\" Record22\",\" Record23 \",\"Record24\",\"Record25\"
\"Record31 \",\" Record32\",\" Record33 \",\"Record34\",\"Record35\"
\"  It's \"\"allowed\"\" to have quotes in strings => double them\",\"val2\",\"val3\",\" \",\"\""""

print("CSV input:\n----------\n" + csv + "\n")

# Regex to match CSV string fields.
csvFieldRegex = re.compile(r"""
    \"              # opening quote.
    \s*             # spaces to drop at the begin.
    (?P<text>       # capturing group named "text"
      (?:           # non-capturing group, repeated 0 or n times, ungreedy.
        \"{2}|[^\"] # either an escaped quote (2 quotes) or any non-quote char.
      )*?
    )
    \s*             # spaces to drop at the end.
    \"(?!\")        # closing quote, not followed by a quote. This is to
                    # make the ungreedy text capturing work correctly.
    """, re.X)

# Substitution to have the trimmed text.
csvFieldSubst = '"\\g<text>"'

# Extract the first line to get the column names.
firstLineMatch = re.match(r"^(.+)\r?\n", csv)
if not firstLineMatch:
    raise Exception("Could not extract the first line of the CSV!")

print("\nFirst line:\n-----------\n" + firstLineMatch.group(1))

# Match all the string fields to count them.
startFieldMatches = csvFieldRegex.findall(firstLineMatch.group(1))
if startFieldMatches:
    nbrCols = len(startFieldMatches)
    print("Number of columns: ", nbrCols)
else:
    raise Exception("Could not extract the fields from the first line!")

# Trim the string fields, but only for the number found on the first line.
result = csvFieldRegex.sub(csvFieldSubst, csv, nbrCols)
if result:
    print("\nResulting CSV:\n--------------\n" + result)
```

Output:

```
CSV input:
----------
"Column1 "," Column2"," Column3 ","Column4","""stupid"",""col"" name "
"Record11 "," Record12"," Record13 ","Record14","Record15"
"Record21 "," Record22"," Record23 ","Record24","Record25"
"Record31 "," Record32"," Record33 ","Record34","Record35"
"  It's ""allowed"" to have quotes in strings => double them","val2","val3"," ",""

First line:
-----------
"Column1 "," Column2"," Column3 ","Column4","""stupid"",""col"" name "
Number of columns:  5

Resulting CSV:
--------------
"Column1","Column2","Column3","Column4","""stupid"",""col"" name"
"Record11 "," Record12"," Record13 ","Record14","Record15"
"Record21 "," Record22"," Record23 ","Record24","Record25"
"Record31 "," Record32"," Record33 ","Record34","Record35"
"  It's ""allowed"" to have quotes in strings => double them","val2","val3"," ",""
```

But personally, I would use a CSV parser and not use regex to do that.
It's not really the good tool for that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to replace just the first line, you should iterate on all lines, and only apply the regex to the initial line.

The following will match the *","*, with zero or more spaces on each side.
And, replace this with *","*.

```
\s*\",\"\s*
```